# Move Duplicate rows into another sheet

Tags: excel, duplicates, move, worksheet, vba

I am lookin for vba code where it should find duplicate rows based on all columns and move those rows to another sheet.

Just like Excel removeduplicate function but I want keep the duplicate values in another sheet.

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any code ?

Comment: Below is the code which I used for deleting duplicate rows but I need deleted rows for data validation.

Answer (score 0):

This code will Cut Duplicate rows on the active worksheet based on Column A.
It will paste the cut rows in the worksheet named "Duplicates".

```
 Sub CutDuplicates()
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set Rng = Range("DH2:DH" & Range("DH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cells(i, "DH")) > 1 Then
              lr = Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(Rows.Count, "DH").End(xlUp).Row + 1
              Rows(i).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & lr)
              Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

This was tested on a 50 row test sheet, but it should also work on your larger row worksheet.

Comment: It's based on column DH, not A.

Comment: my mistake, but it is template, he must modify it, this is only example

Comment: Yes, but it may be misleading for beginners.

Comment: This code checks duplicate rows only in DH column but my requirement is for multiple columns suppose if there are A,B,C, D,,,,,,,Z column then it should consider all A to Z columns if all column's data same then consider as duplicate if single column has different value then it will be consider as unique row.

Answer (score 0):

I have a huge data, to delete duplicate rows I am using the below code. the Column number and row numbers are dynamic always.

```
Sub DeDupe()

Dim intArray As Variant, i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
With rng
    ReDim intArray(0 To .Columns.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(intArray)
        intArray(i) = i + 1
    Next i
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(intArray), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```